# 4 planes in an orthonormal coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, plane-geometry, intersection-theory

[image]

I do not know where to start with this, I've spent two hours searching in my math book and I can't find anything that's relevant enough.

Comment: do you want to use Maple?

Comment: Seems like the solution is a point $[0.4 \,\,0.2 \,\,0.0]^T$. Note $\alpha_2$ and  $\alpha_4$ are redundant. You just solve 3 equations for 3 unknowns.

Comment: Yes, I was able to find the point with Gauss elimination, it's good to know I did this correctly. However how am I supposed to find the parametric equation for the line, with just one point?